# How do I set the user agent in Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have one small strange question: How do I set the user agent in Volley?

I need the **full version** of some sites (desktop version), **not** mobile version.

I tried to change variable userAgent from "volley/0" to something like "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36" (my Chrome). No difference.

Any advice?

Comment: [here are some tutorials](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android/) check this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html shows another way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should override the method getHeaders() in Request and set the "User-agent" header

In your Request class:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("User-agent", "YOUR_USER_AGENT");
    return headers;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @alex's answer you need to add this @Override function to your request object when adding it to the queue.

```
Request request = new Request(
   Method.GET,
   url,
   Listener listener,
   ErrorListener errorListener) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("User-agent", "YOUR_USER_AGENT");
        return headers;
    }
};
```

To understand more about how to add this to your requests, see this StackOverflow answer about setting headers. - [How to set custom header in Volley Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request)