# Volley connection with JSON parameter

Tags: android, parameters, android-volley

Hi i using volley connection in my Android project, i want to connect to rest api.
If i using curl the code is

```
curl -G -H "Content-type:application/json" -d "q={\"order_by\":[{\"field\":\"dates\",\"direction\":\"desc\"}]}" http://testurl/api/v1/test
```

And i do my volley connection like this

```
String x = "{\"order_by\":[{\"field\":\"dates\",\"direction\":\"desc\"}]}";
 JSONObject jo;
try{
    jo = new JSONObject(x);
    JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                             "http://testurl/api/v1/test", 
                    jo, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){                                @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try{Log.i("response",response.toString(3));}
                                catch(JSONException 
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {@Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        });
                queue.add(jreq);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){}
```

connection success but result is not right, i guest because in in api must use q=JSON_SEARCH and in my volley connection i can't put q= in there..

Have anyone have some suggestion for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Good hint is to trace the connection with wireshark, so that you can exactly see the difference. There should be probably used headers in request. Something like here [How to set custom header in Volley Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request)