# Volley StringRequest in Android app

Tags: android, request, android-volley

In my Android app I have a StringRequest and send it using Volley. The problem is that neither onResponse nor onErrorResponse get called!! I use JSONRequest in other part of my application and I have absolutely no problem with it. 
What am I missing?

[Here is one of the samples I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request)

It's been bugging me for a couple of hours and I have no idea what is causing this. Any clue highly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public class AccountManagerProxy  {
StringRequest req;

public void run() {
    try {
        String s1 = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8");
        String s2 = URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8");
        String uri = String.format("http://****/token?grant_type=password&username=%1$s&password=%2$s", s1, s2);
        req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response);
                Log.d("##", "##");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Log.d("@@", "@@");
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String parsed;
                try {
                    parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    parsed = new String(response.data);
                }
                return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        }
        ;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } Singleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

}

Comment: is it possible there is an exception in the try block and the StringRequest line never gets executed? Print a log message at the bottom of try block just to check if it executed or print log in catch block

Comment: Did you come right with this eventually?