# Implementation of volly library for calling webservcies in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I am using below code and Volley lib to call api.
in this just passing method and url , I need to pass headers also.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            "http//xyz", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
```

Comment: you override getHeaders()    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Handle response here
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //Handle errors here
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("HEADER KEY", "HEADER VALUE");
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.
What is requestQueue?

Comment: Request queue is what you add JsonObjectRequest to in order to send your request to the server, you should have something like this in your code  RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext()); where you can then do requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest); Please accept the answer if it helps you @RaminderSidhu

Comment: What to import for Map and HashMap?

Comment: import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map; @RaminderSidhu

Comment: Thank you :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `getHeaders()` for putting header information. Follow this -

```
 private void callToApi(){

 String serverUrl = serverUrl+"&lat="+99.9999+"&lng="+76.9887;

        JsonObjectRequest weatherUpdateRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, serverUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, " JSON: " + response.toString());


                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer ghbgrbhrgt");

                return headers;

            }

        };

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(weatherUpdateRequest);
    }
```