# Add headers to ImageLoader android volley

Tags: java, android, http-headers, android-volley

In my app i have used the ImageLoader to load an image into a NetworkView.

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);

        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return mCache.get(url);
        }            
    });
```

My question is, how can i add Http headers ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17049473/1889768) is the first result I got when I googled. Does it not help you?

Comment: @Abbas no as you can see he is loading an image using ImageLoader which doesn't let you access Request object, so its not possible with ImageLoader directly, even i am struggling to find an answer for this