# How to add a custom header in a Volley request with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I have some code. In Volley code:

```
 val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

 val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            linkTrang,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                mTextView.text = "Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { })
    {

    }
    queue.add(stringRequest)
```

How do I set a header called *Authorization* in this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom header in Volley Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request)

Comment: I need a kotlin code

Comment: Just copy/paste  the Java code, you would get your Kotlin code.

Answer (score 42):

I was able to do it in Kotlin using:

```
    val linkTrang = "YOUR URL"

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    val stringRequest = object: StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, linkTrang,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            Log.d("A", "Response is: " + response.substring(0,500))
        },
        Response.ErrorListener {  }) 
    {
        override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            headers["Authorization"] = "Basic <<YOUR BASE64 USER:PASS>>"
            return headers
        }
    }

    queue.add(stringRequest)
```

It is important to use the **`object`** keyword before the construction of the request in order to be able to override the `getHeaders()` method.

Comment: Up vote for  "It is important to use the object keyword "

Comment: Nice way to use object keyword. Save my day. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you man, you just saved my life! The object keyword is very important.