# How to send a request with headers in volley for kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How do I send a request with headers in volley for Kotlin?

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET,url,Response.Listener { response ->
        textoResultado = "La respuesta es: ${response}"
        Log.d("Esto dice",textoResultado)
    },Response.ErrorListener {
        textoResultado = "Algo salio mal"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Synopsis:

- Add an `object` keyword
- then override behaviour of the `getHeaders` function

Two good examples here:

1. https://adnan-tech.com/pass-headers-with-volley-android-kotlin
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53141982/1847378