# Send token header in json object paramater Volley post

Tags: android, json, post, header, android-volley

I am using post method in volley. I searched and found that `getHeader()` is used to send header in request.The solution was to use `JSONObject request` instead of string request(which i am using currently) but is there a way of sending header through this method? Because in that case I will have to modify a lot of code in many classes. Sorry for the English, I am not a native speaker. 
  The request parameter is a json object. I am sending the parameters using following code.

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", "onResponse: " + response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("This is the error", "Error :" + error.toString());
        }
    })
{
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody()  throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params2.put("AssigneeId",userid);
                params2.put("IssueStatus", "5");
                return new JSONObject(params2).toString().getBytes();
            }
 };
        mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom header in Volley Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request)

Comment: No @VivekMishra i went through this question earlier today. Its using '
Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError' while i am using '            public byte[] getBody()  throws AuthFailureError '  As mentioned in question I know there is a way using jsonobject array instead of string request.

Comment: @VivekMishra please read the question now. Thanks

Comment: what has getBody() to do with getHeaders() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request also has **StringRequest**. Please use the getHeaders() in this way:

```
 public void requestWithSomeHttpHeaders() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://www.somewebsite.com";
        StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
            new Response.Listener<String>() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            }, 
            new Response.ErrorListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("ERROR","error => "+error.toString());
                }
            }
        ) {     
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                    params.put("User-Agent", "Nintendo Gameboy");  
                    params.put("Accept-Language", "fr");

                    return params;  
            }
        };
        queue.add(getRequest);

    }
```

For **JsonObjectRequest**:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(tag, response.toString());
                activity.hideDialog();
                try {
                    activity.onRequestServed(response, code);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(tag, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.e(tag, "Site Info Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.hideDialog();
                try {
                    activity.onRequestServed(null,code);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }) {

            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("key", "Value");
                return headers;
            }
        };
```