# Sending a header for authorization with Volley in Android using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-volley

I am trying to authenticate users  via verification code sent to their emails after the submitting details for sign up.

I have the following code to listen to the code/pin as received via the email but am not sure if I am adding the header/bearer-token the right way as I receive server error on verification.

Kindly assist

```
        var codeEntered:String? = null

        txt_pin_entry.setOnPinEnteredListener {
            codeEntered = "$it"
            Toast.makeText(context!!.applicationContext, "inside $codeEntered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener {


            val url = "https://fathomless-badlands-69782.herokuapp.com/api/auth/verify"
            val params = HashMap<String, String?>()
            params["Authorization"] = "Bearer $tokenCode"
            params["code"] = codeEntered


            Toast.makeText(context!!.applicationContext, "outside $codeEntered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            val jsonObject = JSONObject(params as Map<*, *>)

            val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, jsonObject,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    try{
                        Log.i("Registration", "Response $response")

                    }catch (e: Exception){
                        Log.e("Registration", "Response $e")
                        Toast.makeText(context!!.applicationContext, "Response $response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }, Response.ErrorListener {
                    Log.e("Registration", "Response $it")
                    Toast.makeText(context!!.applicationContext, "Response $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                })



            VolleySingleton.getInstance(context!!.applicationContext).addToRequestQueue(request)
            val actionToVerificationResult = CodeVerificationFragmentDirections.actionToVerificationResult()
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(actionToVerificationResult)
        }

    }
```

The API expects a request as below

```
{
  code: String
}
```

Comment: Question is, why use Volley, when you can use Retrofit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set custom header in Volley Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this below one

```
override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            headers["code"] = Your code
            return headers
        }
```

example:

```
class ServiceVolley : ServiceInterface {
    val TAG = ServiceVolley::class.java.simpleName
    val basePath = "https://your/backend/api/"

    override fun post(path: String, params: JSONObject, completionHandler: (response: JSONObject?) -> Unit) {
        val jsonObjReq = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, basePath + path, params,
                Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "/post request OK! Response: $response")
                    completionHandler(response)
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    VolleyLog.e(TAG, "/post request fail! Error: ${error.message}")
                    completionHandler(null)
                }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json")
                return headers
            }
        }

        BackendVolley.instance?.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, TAG)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please where do I plug in the getHeaders function?

Answer (score 0):

Return header orverridding getHeaders

```
  val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, jsonObject,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                try{
                    Log.i("Registration", "Response $response")

                }catch (e: Exception){
                    Log.e("Registration", "Response $e")
                    Toast.makeText(context!!.applicationContext, "Response $response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                Log.e("Registration", "Response $it")
                Toast.makeText(context!!.applicationContext, "Response $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }){
   @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json")
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer $tokenCode")
            return headers
  }
```