# Is there any way to use API with headers and API KEY using Volley to develop Android App?

Tags: android, json, api, android-volley

I found some good APIs on **RapidApi** i wanted to use for developing Android and iOS apps but those Apis require Headers and API KEY for GET requests and i cant find any tutorial or solution as to how to use such APIs where headers are necessary for using in **Volley.**

Can anyone provide a **sample solution** of using an Api which requires Headers, by getting **JSON** data from such API?

**Is there any solution to this?** And also is there any Better **Alternate to Volley** for such purpose?

RapidApi provide format for only UniRest and OKHttp and what is the way to **translate such format to Volley** for further usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using any API from RapidAPI Hub you have to pass custom headers in the HTTP requests, `x-rapidapi-host` and `x-rapidapi-key`. You can head over to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request) link to learn more about how to add custom header in the Volley request.